# Image sharing to Facebook/Twitter via UIActivityViewController stopped working in iOS 8

Tags: facebook, twitter, ios8, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I had perfectly working code for image sharing in FB/Twitter in iOS 7.

```
- (NSArray *)activityViewController:(NSArray *)activityViewController itemsForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
...
  if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] ||
      [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter])
    return @[@"text", [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
...
}
```

After update to iOS 8 I simply see blank image in the posting window and nothing is posted to social network.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for video sharing. You can try the same for images.

I had video data that I first saved to a file in documents directory and then I attached that file.

```
//write to a file [videoData writeToFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.mov"] atomically:YES];
```

then

```
- (IBAction)ShareVideoWihFacebook:(id)sender {
    //get the file url NSString* path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.mov"];

    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    UIActivityViewController * activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[videoURL,@"Created by ..."] applicationActivities:NULL];

    [activityVC setExcludedActivityTypes:@[ UIActivityTypeMail,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypeMessage,UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll]];
    [activityVC setValue:@"My Video" forKey:@"subject"];

    [activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
        //NSLog(@"completed dialog - activity: %@ - finished flag: %d", activityType, completed);
    }];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```